# How to re-execute javascript code after a fetch JSON function?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Let's say I have a simple HTML with a **fetch script that brings data from a JSON** document to a table.

This same **HTML has a second JavaScript code** (that does thins like a count of the length of the table elements) and **prints that information back to the user**.

But I can't show the new information (updated by the second script) that was brought in by the fetch script. My JavaScript code only updates the table length of the HTML data **before** that was received before the JSON document was fetched.

HTML EXAMPLE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="theTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Starting Code</td> 

            <!-- after the first script execution we get this: -->

            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p>Size of Table: </p>
    <span id="userInformation"></span>

<!-- I wish everytime the JSON data changed and the new data is stored in the table...
 this span would be updated by the second script to apear "3" instead of "1":-->


<script>
fetch('someValues.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        appendData(data);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
    });

function appendData(data) {
    
    //code too insert data from JSON to this HTML file
    
    }

    //Let's supose the data from the JSON file is a vector: vector[1,2,3]
        
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("userInformation").innerHTML = document.getElementById('theTable').rows[0].cells.length;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

A last explanation just in case I wasn't clear:

I basically have **2 javascript** files.

1. **Brings data** from a JSON file to the HTML table
2. **Updates the HTML file** with that same table's information.

Tho every time the script 1 is executed... the script 2 **doesn't execute again updating on top of the new information brought by script 1**. It just analyses what the HTML table started with.

So if it started with 0 elements on the table... the user get's a **"Length of table is 0"** altho we have a lot of elements there brought by JSON.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

A simple refactor would be to wrap the `fetch()` in a function that returns the fetch promise.

Then call this function in your second script and wrap the table row counter in another  `then()`. This new `then()` would run after the one that calls `appendData()`

```
function loadData() {
  // return the fetch promise to next then in chain
  return fetch('someValues.json')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(appendData);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
      throw err
    });
}

// load the data
loadData().then(function(){
   // runs after appendData() in previous then()
   document.getElementById("userInformation").innerHTML = document.getElementById('theTable').rows[0].cells.length;
}).catch(function(err){
   console.log('Oops something went wrong')
})
```

Comment: Woah, what an easy solution haha. Thank you very much! It worked fine

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped